# Optional parameters in OpenERP field definitions

Tags: python, odoo

I couldn't find any documentation of the optional parameters that are available to all [field types](http://doc.openerp.com/developer/2_5_Objects_Fields_Methods/field_type.html) in OpenERP models, so I added what I knew to the [fields documentation page](http://doc.openerp.com/developer/2_5_Objects_Fields_Methods/openerp_fields.html).

There are a bunch of parameters that I don't understand, so I'd appreciate help fleshing out the documentation. You can post answers here, and I'll update the docs, or you can edit the docs yourself. Either one is appreciated.

The specific fields I had questions on are:

- change_default
- context
- priority
- select

The `states` parameter could also use more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that they are still in use this fields ? because i just did a **find /openerp | grep "field"** and i didn't find much code that use them ? and because in my experience with openerp the core code is such a mess it's not the first time that i found such a thing (unused code, unused function ...)

but here is what i find until know maybe it can help you :

- change_default: in documentation that
  you linked change_default is like
  on_change but are you sure,  because
  change_default can be set to (True or
  False ) rather on_change is a string
  where you specify a function that get
  launched when the value is changed in
  the view but here is the only thing i
  found in the code is this :

  #one2many can't be used as condition for defaults 
     assert(self.change_default != True)
- ...

take a look on this too : 
http://openobject.com/wiki/index.php/Developers:Developper%27s_Book/Objects/ObjectsDefine/ObjectsFields

N.B:

1. i have openerp version 5.0.14
2. i will try to add more info as soon as i found more

good luck with the documentation is been a long time that i was waiting a good doc for openerp and up to date

Comment: Thanks for the response. The fields class is very widely used, make sure you're looking in the addons project. Look at any model class like addons/product/product.py product_product._columns (line 426). Of course, some of the parameters that I'm trying to document are not widely used, and that's why I'm asking for help.

Comment: That link looks like exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: @Don Kirkby : the fact that some addons use this fields don't mean that they are still use, because i bet that the openerp shipped addons didn't change from while so it can be that they are still using some old code yes ??